# Generic way to restrict a user's actions on a web application (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, generic-programming, restrictions

I've been tasked to work out a model which will introduce restrictions or levels in an *existing* webapplication. The application is not consequently build to easily implement this feature.
Serverside is PHP, clientside is jQuery.

These restrictions are associated with plans or subscriptions a user has bought.

I've come up with a model where:

- Functions are mapped with actions.
- An Action is a meaningful definition of an act a user can *do* on the application.
- A plan is a list of actions with a meaningful restrictive value.

A real world example

- requestIntroduction() is mapped with 'requesting' <-> 'introduction'
- The action is a 'request' of an 'introduction'
- Current plan allows user to request 5 introductions
- Do the check

I'm looking for a generic way to control restrictions as much as possible in one place in the code because:

- Plans will be added, removed and adjusted frequently
- Restrictions will be added, removed and adjusted frequently (to a plan)
- Adjusting restrictions and plans will be a feature in an admin console in the future.

**My question is :**
Is there a better way to achieve the same generic approach to handle restrictions and to minimize coding future changes to plans and/or restrictions ?

Comment: you can identify each action with an id/codename and have a table somewhere defining wich actions each user group/user has

Comment: @EnoqueDuarte Yea, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you define your Actions methods like "emptyBinAction", "gothereAction" on a controller (admiting you are using MVC or similar design pattern)

you can easly check the permission based on method names:

example:

```
protected function emptyBinAction($params) {
    $this->checkAccess();

    ...
}
```

for example, you can use `checkAccess()` to check login + if user has permission to this action:

```
protected function checkAccess() {  
     // Check login 
     if ($this->myModel->checkLogin()) {
         // Query DB for permission (pass user id and func name)
         if (!$this->myModel->checkPerm($usrId,$this->getCallerName()) ) {
             return false;
         }
     }
 ...
}
```

example method to return caller name (in this case will return "emptyBinAction"):

```
public function getCallerName() {
    $e = new Exception();
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    return $trace[2]['function'];
}
```

in terms of the checkPerm() query and db structure you can do as you wish, either attribute permisions to user groups, or to each user, or both.

Comment: Your proposal is exactly what I had in mind, except of using a function like you define with getCallerName(), I was thinking of the PHP magic constant [__ FUNCTION __](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). Would this be advisable ?

Comment: as i see in php manual, __FUNCTION__ value is lower cased, so its up to you, i see there too __METHOD__ wich is case sensitive, but never tested it, might work  :http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: According to the docs, the constant returns lower cased string in PHP 4 but case-sensitive in PHP 5 and above. Tested it and works as described. The platform uses PHP 5.3 so I think it's safe to use the constant.